# While testing routes of my django prodject, i got Type error: expected sting or bites like object. How i can fix this error?

Tags: django, pytest, django-fixtures

The page of the published news on my blog, is available to any user. I use pytest to check if the page is accessible to an anonymous user.
Url is formed by using the id of the news, which I pass in the address parameters (as a tuple).

In the result I got this Type error. test_pages_availability[news:detail-news] - TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I had tried to format args to str, puted a coma after arg for tuple format, it didn't helped

code of test

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'name, args',
    (
        ('news:detail', pytest.lazy_fixture('news')),
        ('news:home', None),
        ('users:login', None),
        ('users:logout', None),
        ('users:signup', None),
    )
)
def test_pages_availability(client, name, args):
    if args is not None:
        url = reverse(name, args=(news.id,))
    else:
        url = reverse(name)
    response = client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == HTTPStatus.OK
```

`
fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def news():
    news = News.objects.create(
        title='Новость',
        text='Невероятное событие',
        date=datetime.today,
    )
    return news
```

```
class NewsDetail(generic.DetailView):
model = News
template_name = 'news/detail.html'

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj = get_object_or_404(
        self.model.objects.prefetch_related('comment_set__author'),
        pk=self.kwargs['pk']
    )
    return obj

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        context['form'] = CommentForm()
    return context
```

Traceback:

```
request = <FixtureRequest for <Function test_pages_availability[news:detail-news]>>

def fill(request):
    item = request._pyfuncitem
    fixturenames = getattr(item, "fixturenames", None)
    if fixturenames is None:
        fixturenames = request.fixturenames

    if hasattr(item, 'callspec'):
        for param, val in sorted_by_dependency(item.callspec.params, fixturenames):
            if val is not None and is_lazy_fixture(val):
```

> ```
>               item.callspec.params[param] = request.getfixturevalue(val.name)
> ```

value = <built-in method today of type object at 0x00007FFE9CA83650>

```
def parse_date(value):
    """Parse a string and return a datetime.date.

    Raise ValueError if the input is well formatted but not a valid date.
    Return None if the input isn't well formatted.
    """
```

> ```
>   match = date_re.match(value)
> ```

E       TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

..\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py:75: TypeError

Comment: Please share the `detail` view...

Comment: as well as the full traceback, please [edit] the question.

Comment: @VladmirShevckenko: can you add the *full* traceback as well? So not just the top of the error, but all "ancester calls".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data=` parameter is not a date, it is a function to convert it into a `date`. You need to *call* the method, so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def news():
    return News.objects.create(
        title='Новость',
        text='Невероятное событие',
        date=datetime.today(),
    )
```

For a [**`default=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#default) you can indeed pass a *callable* that Django will then call, but not as a value, the value is then the *result* of the function call, not the function itself.